# fetching event as json in FullCalendar error: undefined fonction near $ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to hydrate the FullCalendar with som customs events and every time I try to use the Ajax or Json `events` I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function near (...$.ajax...)
```

here is the javascript code of my FullCalendar :

```
$(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar..

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        header:{
            left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,today,next'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        weekNumbers: true, 
        weekNumberTitle: "Week",
        slotLabelFormat: 'H:mm',
        nowIndicator: true,
        navLinks: true,

        events: getEvents
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found out that I was loading the slim version of Jquery (a bad cut/paste operation I imagine) which does not include the ajax function.

I hope it will help someone